# GAE: BadValueError while updating the schema of existing entities

Tags: database, google-app-engine, schema, database-schema

I'm using this code to update the schema of existing entities:

```
            photo = Photo.get_by_id( 334 )
            photo.smThumb = db.BlobProperty()
            photo.mThumb = db.BlobProperty()
            photo.lgThumb = db.BlobProperty()
            photo.put()

            photo.smThumb = photo.sm_thumbnail
            photo.mThumb = photo.lg_thumbnail
            photo.lgThumb = photo.lg_thumbnail
            photo.put()
```

which results in:

```
BadValueError: Property smThumb must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument     should be str instance, not BlobProperty)
```

How do I fix this?

**note:** sm_thumbnail and lg_thumbnail both are of type db.BlobProperty() and currently have binary values (a photo for each). I'm trying to copy those values over to the new properties smThumb, mThumb, and lgThumb.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Rewrite.

Same error can come when you access an objects BlobProperty-field when that field is not initialized and object is not yet saved. If the field holds any content (even empty string) it will be of type Blob. Maybe your problem is related to this.

Answer originally presented [here](http://markmail.org/message/zywqvfs5dcmtikv5#query%3a+page:1+mid%3azywqvfs5dcmtikv5+state%3aresults).

Comment: Not true - a BlobProperty will never return itself.

Comment: @NickJohnson Added source, thought it was reliable and it worked in that case.

Comment: That post is just describing how properties work in general - even if you don't initialize it, it won't return the property class.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing us your model, but I'm guessing it looks something like this:

```
class Photo(db.Model):
  sm_thumbnail = db.BlobProperty
  # ...

  smThumb = db.BlobProperty()
```

Note the missing parens on the definition of `sm_thumbnail`. Without them, you're not making `sm_thumbnail` an instance of a BlobProperty, you're making it an alias for the BlobProperty class. Add the missing parens and you should be fine.